# Prove that $a_n$ converges.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, proof-verification, cauchy-sequences

let $b_n$ be a positive sequence. s.t. for each $\epsilon>0$ there is N s.t. for each $m>n>N$:

$ \sum_{k=n}^mb_k <\epsilon$

and let $a_n$ be a sequence that fulfills that for each $n\in  \mathbb N$:

$|a_{n+1}-a_n|\le b_n$

prove that $a_n$ converges.

my solution: by looking at the first terms in the sequence $a_n$ i noticed that :

$$ |a_{n+1}-a_n| \le b_n$$
$$.$$
$$.$$
$$ |a_{m-1}-a_{m-2}| \le b_{m-2}$$
$$ |a_{m}-a_{m-1}| \le b_{m-1}$$
$$ |a_{m+1}-a_{m}| \le b_{m}$$

using the first given information we get that by choosing every desired $\epsilon$ there is an $N$ s.t. for every $m>n>N$ we get:

$|b_n+b_{n+1} + b_{n+2} + .. + b_m|<\epsilon$ (because every element in the sum is positive)

by summing the inequalities I wrote above:

$|a_{m+1}-a_{n}| = |a_{n+1} - a_n +...+ a_{m-1} - a_{m-2} + a_m - a_{m-1} + a_{m+1} - a_m| \le |a_{n+1}-a_n| + |a_{n}-a_{n-1}|+...+|a_{m-1}-a_{m-2}| + |a_{m}-a_{m-1}| +|a_{m+1}-a_{m}| \le |b_n+b_{n+1} + b_{n+2} + .. + b_m|<\epsilon$

then we define $m+1 = n+p$, where $p \in \mathbb Z$, and we can do this because $m>n$. so by Cauchy's test, $a_n$ converges.

do you think my solution is okay?
any kind of help would be appreciated.

Comment: The first sentence is rather confusing, I can't understand what $a_n$ or $b_n$ really are. Could you try rewording that?

Comment: Do you mean $\sum_{k=n}^m b_k < \epsilon$ in the first sentence?

Comment: I can't believe I missed the $\epsilon$ . thanks @Ian

Comment: Do you mean to say that $m>n$, not vise versa?

Comment: @BigbearZzz try to substitute some numbers from $n$ to $m$ in 
$|a_{n+1}-a_n|\le b_n$ and u will get the same sequence. instead, i choose to describe the elements by $m$ and $n$ just for the sake of proof.

Comment: @BigbearZzz yes, edited that too. something wrong with editing, its not updating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$|a_{k}-a_h| = |a_k - a_{k+1} + a_{k+1} - \dots +a_{h+1} - a_h| \leq $$
$$ \leq |a_k - a_{k-1}| + |a_{k-1} - a_{k-2}| + \dots +|a_{h+1} - a_h| \leq b_{k-1} + \dots + b_h = \sum_{i=h}^{k-1} b_i \leq \varepsilon $$
for $k,h$ large enough. So $a_n$ is Cauchy, therefore converges.

Comment: What is the difference between this and what I did ?

Comment: None, but I didn't see the (proof-verification) tag so I gave a complete answer

Comment: @actually you helped me know such tag exist:) thanks.